# Liquibase: How to configure the value of failonerror attribute for live and test environments

Tags: sql, sql-server, liquibase

I have a bunch of changesets to execute in test environmets. But when I run these changesets on live I need to set `failonerror = false` to avoid breaking the deployment of the rest of the changes.
Is there a way I can configure the value of this attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The supported way to do this in liquibase is to use [contexts](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/contexts). This enables you to control which changesets (and their associated attributes like "failonerror") are run during an upgrade.

Comment: Agree! But I don't wanna use that because then i'll end up having duplicate changesets. e.g.
  <changeSet id ="c49c5a32-784c-49cb-8735-85563fdc6711" context="Staging" author="Nadeem" >
</changeset>

  <changeSet id ="c49c5a32-784c-49cb-8735-85563fdc6711" context="Live" author="Nadeem">
</changeset>

Comment: @Nadeem Understood, which is why I'm very sparing in my use of contexts (Normally reserved for loading data into tables). It's not clear to me why you need to do what you're trying to do. Normally I want my migration to execute against test in exactly same manner that it is to be applied to production.

Comment: So normally if anything breaks, the deployment stops immediately which leaves the server with a partial deployment, even if the rest of the changes were correct and could have run successfully if allowed to. So I just want to allow the rest of the changes to run, but at the same time I don't want this to happen in staging because I want these things to be caught.

Comment: @Nadeem I understand, but it's still not a good idea in my opinion. I'd be afraid of cascading errors, for example a series of failing table inserts because the table creation step failed first. Stopping the migration immediately is better because at least you can understand the current state of the database and be sure it matches your staging DB. I'd be concerned that production and staging would drift apart too far and cause even more problems.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I'll probably drop the idea of using liquibase directly on live as I don't have enough confidence yet. I'll rather use liquibase to generate sql files which I can run on live.